# filter multiple products from single table in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i am trying to filter multiple products from database using php. i have check box in html page with 4 category,the values will be stored in a array on submit values post to php page , where data is filtered. see below example.

[image]

bellow is my html

```
<input class="le-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="filter1[]" value="<?=$bkey?>" /> <label><?=$bkey?></label>
<input class="le-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="filter2[]" value="<?=$bkey?>" /> <label><?=$bkey?></label>
<input class="le-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="filter3[]" value="<?=$bkey?>" /> <label><?=$bkey?></label>
<input class="le-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="filter4[]" value="<?=$bkey?>" /> <label><?=$bkey?></label>
```

values are stored in  `filter1[],filter2[],filter3[],filter4[]`

in php

```
$filter1=$_POST['filter1'];
$filter2=$_POST['filter2'];
$filter3=$_POST['filter3'];
```

and also implode

i

```
f(isset($filter1)){

        $pbrand= implode(",",$filter1);

        }
    if(!empty($filter2)){

        $pcolor= implode(",",$filter2);

        }
        if(!empty($filter3)){

        $pfab= implode(",", $filter3);

        }
```

now check with mysql

```
$result = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM products_list WHERE status='Available' AND brand IN (?) OR color IN (?) OR fabric IN (?)");
        //$result->bindValue(1, $status);
        $result->bindValue(1, $pbrand);
        $result->bindValue(2, $pcolor);
        $result->bindValue(3, $pfab);
```

its working fine when i select single checkbox from each category. when i check multiple checkbox from single catagory, its not working and also my condition `status='Available'` not working i don't understand why its not working

Comment: You've used OR, but surely you want AND !?!? WHERE x IN(...) AND y IN(...) AND z IN(...)??? Also, you appear to be talking about just 100 or so products. For such a tiny dataset, I'd consider just grabbing the entire thing and handling the filtering entirely within JavaScript

Comment: ok i don't have much knowledge in JavaScript can you solve my problem with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM products_list WHERE status='Available' AND (brand IN (?) OR color IN (?) OR fabric IN (?))"
```

brackets is need after AND

Comment: 'I want a leatherette bag or a black bag' seems like an unlikely request. A more plausible request might be 'I'm after a black, leatherette bag'

Comment: now status is working but multiple checkbox selection still not working please see above pic for better understanding. if select 2 checkbox form brand not working